# Categorize the data into three groups (positive,negative) (positive,positive) (negative,negative) based on $3 and $2

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk, categories

If we have an input

```
95 cpd-1 -3.21 ooo
56 cpd-1  1.21 ooo
77 cpd-1  2.2  ooo 
93 cpd-2  2.0  oox
57 cpd-2  1.15 oox
85 cpd-3 -1.32 xxx
67 cpd-3 -2.22 xxx
58 cpd-4  0    oxo
65 cpd-4  1.23 oxo
```

And we would love to separate the inputs into three files based on the following rules:

(1) If the column 2 are the same among rows

(2) Separate these rows into three categories: their the column 3 are (positive,negative) (positive,positive) (negative,negative)

(3) We count the 0 in the column 3 as a "positive"

(4) For the same the column 2, their column 1 will definitely be different

(5) For the same the column 2, their column 4 will definitely be the same

The only thing we can think of is to count the minus sign "-".  In (positive,positive),(positive,negative), (negative,negative), no. of minus =1,2,3 accordingly and based on this to do the category.

The desire outputs are: (Don't need to print out ((positive,positive)), etc.)

(positive,positive)

```
93 cpd-2  2.0  oox
57 cpd-2  1.15 oox
58 cpd-4  0    oxo
65 cpd-4  1.23 oxo
```

(positive,negative)

```
95 cpd-1 -3.21 ooo
56 cpd-1  1.21 ooo
77 cpd-1  2.2  ooo
```

(negative,negative)

```
85 cpd-3 -1.32 xxx
67 cpd-3 -2.22 xxx
```

We would like to see if there might be any comment/solution or built in bash/awk/python/perl/etc. functions which can do the trick and we are not aware of.  Thanks!

Comment: please convert the $ in values to column number so that it will be easy to understand for us :)

Comment: ``intertools.groupby`` comes to mind.

Comment: so if there x in the between o it is consider as positive and if there all 0 it is postive negitive and all xxx it is negative negative . is it right?

Comment: If they are all 0, they are positive positive. The column 4 doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do a two stage filter, as you need to perform the initial grouping by column 2 followed by the inspection of the values of column 3. The initial grouping should populate a dictionary, as presumably the column 2 values can vary quite a bit:

```
grouped_rows = {}
for row in rows:
    second_column = row.split(" ")[1]
    if second_column in grouped_rows:
        grouped_rows[second_column].append(row)
    else:
        grouped_rows[second_column] = [row]
```

Then you need to determine if positive or negative values exist in a given group:

```
def row_value(row):
    return float(row.split(" ")[2])

for rows in grouped_rows.values():
    has_positive = any([ row_value(row) >= 0 for row in rows ])
    has_negative = any([ row_value(row) < 0 for row in rows ])

    if has_positive and not has_negative:
        write_rows(file_1, rows)
    elif has_positive and has_negative:
        write_rows(file_2, rows)
    else:
        write_rows(file_3, rows)
```

Comment: Thanks.  May I know which version of python you use?

Comment: it is an elegant solution!

Comment: I use python 2.7. I do not believe that anything in the above code breaks in python 3, but I am not 100% on that.